# Create and Update Images with PHP API

Tags: php, bigcommerce

I'm using bigcommerce.php to create and update products.

Can image information be included in the product arrays that are passed to `updateProduct()` and `createProduct()` or are there any other API functions for images?

Answer (score 3):

for image your need to use the api resource library and use the following class for image and set your custom fields.
    for that all classes and other resource file is available at the below github link

https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php/search?q=image&ref=cmdform